# Hundreds of concurrent task chain

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a scenario that need to handle hundreds of concurrent task chain. Say I need to talk to hundreds of clients in real time. I am using websocket for each client and in each socket connection, I will use `task.ContinueWith` to chain each async send in order.

The system performs well if I only have <500 clients. But when I start to have 800+ clients, my clients starts to see a long task execution delay.

However, the CPU is not exhausted at that time. So I am wondering whether .NET (I am using .NET Framework 4.7) will threshold in the max concurrent task chain execution? Is there anyway to optimize it?

Below is the code sample.

```
internal virtual Task SendAsync(ArraySegment<byte> message,
    WebSocketMessageType messageType, bool endOfMessage, ILogger log, string source)
{
    if (GetWebSocketState(WebSocket) != WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        return TaskAsyncHelper.Empty;
    }
    var sendContext = new SendContext(null, this, message, messageType, endOfMessage,
        ConnectionId, source);


    return _sendQueue.Enqueue2(async (preTask, state) =>
    {
        var context = (SendContext)state;
        switch (preTask.Status)
        {
            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                await SocketSendAsync(source, context);
                break;
            default:
                log.Error("WebSocketHandler Enqueue2 SendAsync failed. source:{source}"
                    + " connectionId:{connectionId} send duration:{duration}"
                    + " task queue:{sendQueueCount} msg size:{payloadSize}"
                    + " msg:{msgContext}",
                    context.Source,
                    this.ConnectionId,
                    _sendQueue.Count,
                    context.Message.Count,
                    context.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text
                        ? context.Message.GetString() : "binary");
                break;
        }
    },
    sendContext,
    log);
}

protected async Task SocketSendAsync(string source, SendContext context)
{
    if (GetWebSocketState(context.Handler.WebSocket) != WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await context.Handler.WebSocket
              .SendAsync(context.Message, context.MessageType, context.EndOfMessage,
              CancellationToken.None);
        log.Debug("WebSocketHandler Enqueue2 SendAsync source:{source}"
            + " connectionId:{connectionId} send duration:{duration} task"
            + " queue:{sendQueueCount} msg size:{payloadSize} msg:{msgContext}",
            context.Source,
            this.ConnectionId,
            stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            _sendQueue.Count,
            context.Message.Count,
            context.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text ?
                context.Message.GetString() : "binary");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex, "WebSocketHandler Enqueue2 SendAsync failed source:{source}"
            + " connection: {connectionId} msg size:{msgSize} task"
            + " queue:{taskQueueCount} send message:{msg}",
            source,
            context.ConnectionId,
            context.Message.Count,
            _sendQueue.Count,
            context.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text ?
                context.Message.GetString() : "binary");
        OnError(ex);
    }
}

public virtual Task Enqueue2(Func<Task, object, Task> taskFunc, object state,
    ILogger trace)
{
    // Lock the object for as short amount of time as possible
    _lastQueuedTask = _lastQueuedTask.ContinueWith<Task>(taskFunc, state,
        CancellationToken.None);
    return _lastQueuedTask;
}
```

Comment: Recently I've found [Concurrency visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2019) from Microsoft. It might shed light on where time is being spent.

Comment: Could you include in the question the relevant code that uses the `ContinueWith` method? Which btw is a [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) method, and should be used with caution.

Comment: One possible explanation is `ThreadPool` saturation, in case there is blocking code in the `ContinueWith` delegates. Could you try adding this line at the start of the program: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000);`, and see if it makes any difference? This is not suggested as a fix, but as a way to troubleshoot the issue you are observing.

Comment: "... chain each async send in order." Do you mean that you are sending data to all connected web sockets, one after another? If one client has a busy TCP connection, sending the data would block the rest? Post your code. We can't tell what you are actually doing without it.

Comment: If you have 800+ open and sending network connections the bottleneck might be the IO and not the runtime. You may should consider switching hardware and look into horizontal scaling options for your app

Comment: Why not just await each Task in a loop?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman each websocket has its own task chain for sending. So it is independent from others.  That's why I am wondering the number of concurrent task chain is the bottle neck here.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I only have await in the ContinueWith. It is not blocking.

Comment: The way you are using the `ContinueWith` is probably wrong. The `.ContinueWith<Task>(...` returns a `Task<Task>`, which you are most probably storing in a variable of type `Task`. Which is legal because the type `Task<T>` inherits from the type `Task`. So each new task does not wait until the *completion* of the previous task, but only until its *creation*, which is probably not your intention. To fix this problem you must chain an `.Unwrap()` after the `ContinueWith`. Btw check out [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) blog post by Stephen Cleary.